# Git push problems

Tags: linux, git, github

i am new to webdeveloping and stuff, I want to push my html and css files to github but after I do `git commit` and `git push origin master` I get this error:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I am new and I couldn't find the answer online.  I looked into several tutorials and did not succeed in pushing my page to GitHub.  I have managed to update my `README.md` file using this tutorial: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/), you need to configure your `origin` to point to the GitHub remote:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
# Set a new remote

git remote -v
# Verify new remote
```

Replace `https://github.com/user/repo.git` with the actual path to your remote repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have the repository uploaded remotely (ie. on Github).

Follow these instructions if you want the repository pushed to GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/. You seem to have done the first 6 steps already (up to committing). **Note:** you require a GitHub account for this and the repository will be publicly available to read unless you pay (don't worry - people won't be able to write into the repository unless you let them).